# Text on top of a formatting line

Tags: formatting

I have the problem that I want to design a sheet with information about the final thesis in which I want to put the name of the teacher and just below a black line of formatting. As I currently have the code only shows the line.
I have tried to put the text before the `\hrulefill` but I can't get the effect I am looking for.

```
\begin{titlepage}
{\flushright \LARGE \textsc{Tutores:}}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: \hrulefill}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher2: \hrulefill}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
{\flushright \LARGE \textsc{Date:} \hrulefill}

\vspace*{\stretch{1.5}}
{\flushright \LARGE \textsc{Grade:} \hrulefill}

\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X X X}
        {\large \textsc{Teacher1}} &
        {\large \textsc{Teacher2}} \\[2.5cm]

        Fdo.: & Fdo.:
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\cleardoublepage
\end{titlepage}
```

**Update:**

I want to create the format that allow me to write any word at the top of the file created with `\hrulefill`. I tried the following:

`\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: John Doe \hrulefill}`

In this case, the name John appears followed by a line created by `\hrulefill` but not at the top as I'm looking for.

Comment: `{\flushright \LARGE \textsc{Tutores:}}` doesn't put the text at the right as you finish the group before the paragraph, use `\par` or a blank line before the `}`

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood you or if I have expressed well what I was looking for. I've added the \par to the line you told me about, but if I do `\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: Ryan \hrulefill}` what I'm looking for is that the name Ryan is written on top of the line I create with `\hrulefill`

Comment: leave a blank line before the rule and use `\rule` not `\hrulefill` , `\hrulefill is a continuation line to complete the current line like teh dotfill used in tables of contents

Comment: Like this?

`\vspace*{\stretch{1.5}}
{\flushright \LARGE \textsc{Teacher1:} Ryan \\}
\rule`

Comment: sorry I meant `\hrule` not `\rule` but also you still have `\flushright` , and don't use `\\ ` use a blank line or `\par`

Comment: @Developer: are you just looking for `\underline`? As in `\Large Teacher 1: \underline{Ryan}`? Or do you need the line to extend all the way to the right? As it stands it is really hard to understand what the criterion is. Is it possible to create a mock-up of a desired output? Take a screen-grab of what "almost" works, and then use graphics software to add the missing bits to the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a more uniform appearance and can input the objects more easily if you define some local commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
% some local settings for ease of typing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\RULED}[3]{%
  \par\hspace*{1cm}%
  \raisebox{5pt}{#1#2: \makebox[0pt][l]{\Large\quad #3}} % we want a space
  \hrulefill\par
}
\newcommand{\signature}[1]{%
  \makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\large #1 \\[2.5cm] F.do: \end{tabular}%
  }\ignorespaces
}

{\LARGE \textsc{Tutores:}}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}

\RULED{\Large}{Teacher 1}{Albert Einstein}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}

\RULED{\Large}{Teacher 2}{John von Neumann}

\vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}

\RULED{\LARGE}{\textsc{Date}}{February 21, 2024}

\vspace*{\stretch{1.5}}

\RULED{\LARGE}{\textsc{Grade}}{}

\vspace*{\stretch{2.5}}

\signature{Teacher 1}
\signature{Teacher 2}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

You can leave the third argument to `\RULED` empty or fill it in with something.

Point to note: never use `\flushleft` and `\flushright`: they exist because of the similarly named environments. The command versions are, respectively `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one of the following solves your problem?

[image]

The first is created using `\underline`. The second is created using `\rlap`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: \hrulefill}

\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: \underline{Ryan}}

\hspace*{1cm}{\Large Teacher1: \rlap{Ryan}\hrulefill}

\end{document}
```